# GET method arabic parameters doesn't work magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rest-api

I'm building rest api to get **products filtered** by **specific attribute**, when I pass parameter for **GET** method in **arabic** I get

> request doesn't match any route

and when I send it using **POST** method it works

**Update:**
here is endpoint definition

```
<route url="/V1/Attributes/filter/:attribute" method="GET">
    <service class="\vendor\Attributes\Api\Attributes\MyAttributesInterface" method="getproducts"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Vendor_Attributes::attributes"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Comment: show us your endpoint definition from webapi.xml. you can't interchange the methods. if you want to use both, you have to define both

Comment: @PhilippSander I've updated post

Comment: is this your only route definition? or do you also have specified one for POST?

Comment: @PhilippSander no, that's it only